# Taylor series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-v^2)}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I don't seem to get the answer the book *"The Geometry of Spacetime"* by Callahan does e.g. $1 + 1/2(v^2) + O(v^4)$ on *Pg. $100$* and it is rather crucial for the ensuing discussion

Comment: Does this mean that we need to read p.100 of the book?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Use the definition: $f(v) = f(0) + f'(0) v + f''(0) v^2/2 + \ldots$. Compute $f(0)$, $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ and you have your result.

Comment: Thanks -- evaluating the results at v = 0 makes all the horrible stuff go away

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series of $(1+x)^\alpha$ (for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and $x\in(-1,1)$ ) is the so called *binomial series*.

$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom \alpha kx^k$$

Where the generalized binomial is $\binom\alpha k=\frac{\alpha\cdot(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$. In your case you are looking at $(1+x)^{-1/2}$ with $x=-v^2$.

Comment: If the OP cannot understand the expression in his/her text book, it is doubtful that this answer will be of much use.

Comment: Sometimes one works in vain.

Comment: @MarkViola , OP doesn't even know how to use MathJax. How is it that they got such a high reputation?

Comment: @evaristegd You, the OP and I have by no means a high reputation. Also, sound questions sometimes get upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The square root is locally Lipschitz (even differentiable) for positive arguments. Thus $\sqrt{a+\epsilon}=\sqrt{a}+O(\epsilon)$ for $a>0$. With that transform
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1-v^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+v^2}}{1+O(v^4)}=\sqrt{1+v^2+\frac{v^4}4}+O(v^4)=1+\frac{v^2}2+O(v^4)
$$

This could be extended to higher orders,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1-v^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+v^2+v^4}}{\sqrt{1-v^6}}=\sqrt{(1+\frac{v^2}2)^2+\frac{3v^4}4}+O(v^6)=...=1+\frac{v^2}2+\frac{3v^4}8+O(v^6)
$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to consider the Taylor series 
$$(1-v)^{-1/2}=(1-0)^{-1/2}+\frac12(1-0)^{3/2}v+o(v)$$

and plug $v^2$, giving

$$(1-v^2)^{-1/2}=1+\frac12v^2+o(v^2).$$